# Angular tree from folder structure

Tags: php, angular, typescript, directory, tree

I'm trying to create a tree that shows on the front end. 
The user gives a location which the backend reads and creates a tree from and sends this back.
This tree can look many different ways. How can i get it so that the front end reads this and created the right tree for it? 
example: 
Frontend sends the path: `/usr/test/dir1/`
Backend reads this with the following function:

```php
function dirtree($dir)
{
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $return = array();

    foreach ($dh as $folder) {
        if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $folder)) {
                $return[] = array($folder => $this->dirtree($dir . '/' . $folder));
            } else {
                $return[] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Backend returns something like:

```
{
    "maindir": [
        ".DS_Store",
        {
            "dir1": []
        },
        {
            "subdir1": [
                ".DS_Store",
                {
                    "subdir2": [
                        {
                            "subdir3": []
                        },
                        {
                            "subdir4": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
}
```

How can I translate this to the front-end? 
Or how can I add a type children to this?

Comment: Do users' access server files on the front end?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! What have you tried on the Angular side to achieve what you are trying to do? Can you post some sample code. Thanks!

Comment: @vivek_23 The user has to fill in the path manually by copying the folder path out of their finder/explorer.

Comment: @ulmas I have not tried anything on the front end since im not sure on how to implement this method since I have no default value. if you know what I mean